# How do I exclude certain text in an HTML p tag with Nokogiri using CSS selectors?

Tags: html, css, ruby, nokogiri

I am dealing with HTML that follows the structure below.  I want to ignore "RANDOM TEXT" and  want to pull "TEXT I WANT" with a CSS selector.

The selector I am using right now is pulling all of the text:

```
variable = page.css('div.eight.columns.listingDetail p')
```

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="eight columns listingDetail">
<p>
<span class="bold">RANDOM TEXT</span>
TEXT I WANT 1
</p>
<p>
<span class="bold">RANDOM TEXT</span>
<span class="bold price">
TEXT I WANT 2
<span></span>
</span>
</p>
<p>
<span class="bold">RANDOM TEXT</span>
</p>
<p>
<span class="bold">RANDOM TEXT</span>
TEXT I WANT 3
</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So get first `p` and inside it find last element and get its text:

```
puts page.css('div.eight.columns.listingDetail p').first.children.last.text
```

And find `span` with `bold` and `price` classes inside one of the `p` element and get text:

```
puts page.css('div.eight.columns.listingDetail p span.bold.price').text
```

And for last one:

```
puts doc.css('div.eight.columns.listingDetail p').last.children.last.text
```

Comment: thank you. this was very helpful.  I was wondering... is it possible to write a css selector that pulls everything that is NOT something i.e. ('div.eight.columns.listingDetail p !span.bold.price)?!

Comment: Sure, you can use `not`. For example, for your case, if you need to get all `spans` that do not have class `price` you could do this: `puts doc.css('div p span:not(.price)').text`

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'd do:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<div class="eight columns listingDetail">
<p>
<span class="bold">RANDOM TEXT</span>
TEXT I WANT 1
</p>
<p>
<span class="bold">RANDOM TEXT</span>
<span class="bold price">
TEXT I WANT 2
<span></span>
</span>
</p>
<p>
<span class="bold">RANDOM TEXT</span>
</p>
<p>
<span class="bold">RANDOM TEXT</span>
TEXT I WANT 3
</p>
</div>
EOT

spans = doc.search('span.bold')
spans[0].next_sibling.text # => "\nTEXT I WANT 1\n"
spans[2].text              # => "\nTEXT I WANT 2\n\n"
spans[4].next_sibling.text # => "\nTEXT I WANT 3\n"
```

The idea with parsing is to find your landmarks, node combinations that help you locate your target. It's best when there are repeating patterns so you can quickly search. In this case, the `span class="bold"` was the minimum needed to locate the desired text, only there was one extra necessary to ignore.

There are other ways to get there, but this keeps it simple.